# logical optimisation using Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have made a resolve function using Ramda that works like a charms, but I'm pretty sure it could be simplified, unfortunately I'm struggling to get over this optimisation

I want to group the values into a structure that has a 'name' and 'y' is the count. For instance, if 'pending' appear two times, and 'hired' once in my input, then I would like to get what you see in the output

The function I wrote

```js
const aggResumeStatusTest = data =>
  reduce(
    (acc, elem) => {
      if (!isEmpty(acc)) {
        const indexInArray = findIndex(propEq('name', elem))(acc);
        if (indexInArray !== -1) {
          acc[indexInArray].y++;
        } else {
          acc.push({
            name: elem,
            y: 1,
          });
        }
        return acc;
      }

      acc.push({
        name: elem,
        y: 1,
      });

      return acc;
    },
    [],
    data,
  );

aggResumeStatusTest(['pending', 'pending', 'hired'])
```

input

```js
['pending', 'pending', 'hired']
```

output

```js
[ { name: 'pending', y: 2 }, { name: 'hired', y: 1 } ]
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether this counts as an optimization but your code CAN be simplified.

First, there's `R.groupBy` to group all these strings. So you can go from:

```
['pending', 'pending', 'hired']
```

To:

```
[['pending', 'pending'], 'hired']
```

The twist is, it returns an object instead and we are only insterested in its values so we use `R.values`.

Then all you have to do is map over it and gets its length.

So in the end you have:

```
let countToObj = arr => ({name : R.head(arr), y: arr.length })
R.map(countToObj, R.values(R.groupBy(R.identity, data)));
```

```js
let countToObj = arr => ({name : R.head(arr), y: arr.length })
let aggResumeStatusTest = data => R.map(countToObj, R.values(R.groupBy(R.identity, data)));
console.log(aggResumeStatusTest(['pending', 'pending', 'hired']));
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.21.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works only for sorted inputs because adjacent items are passed to the comparison.

Comment: `groupBy` works more the way I think you want.  But `countBy` is more semantic.

Comment: I was hoping for `groupBy` with array (as a return value) but I guess there isn't one. So, I'll just use `R.values`.

Comment: @MinusFour: Yes, that isn't there, but it should be.  Feel free to raise an [Issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/new) or even better a [Pull Request](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/compare) for this.

Comment: thank you to all for that one, this help me a lot

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty easy task to accomplish with ramda,
please do take a look at [`R.countBy`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#countBy);

```js
const count = R.pipe(
  R.countBy(R.identity),
  R.toPairs,
  R.map(([name, y]) => ({ name, y })),
)


// ====

const data = ['pending', 'pending', 'hired'];

console.log(
  count(data),
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.js" integrity="sha512-3sdB9mAxNh2MIo6YkY05uY1qjkywAlDfCf5u1cSotv6k9CZUSyHVf4BJSpTYgla+YHLaHG8LUpqV7MHctlYzlw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: The *only* problem here (which is pretty minor) is that the inputs are converted to strings. So, attempting this with numbers will return strings. And attempting this with a mix `[1, "1", 2]` will group together the `1`s , even if they are different types. IMO, it's not a problem, as I'd expect the input to only be strings but mentioning it *just in case*. The counts can be done into a Map to preserve the types. If needed, of course, I suspect the vast majority time, it wouldn't be.

Comment: well, the OP was clear about the `string[]` input, of course a different input type would require a redesign of this algorithm...

Comment: As I said, it's a very minor problem. More of a note for the future, if anybody comes across this and happens to want to group other types. I do believe the answer is correct, I don't have any objections.

Comment: It wouldn't work with objects either but I guess that's also not part of the problem.

Comment: I hadn't seen yours when I posted my very similar solution.  Great minds, and all that!  I'm not sure if I prefer your lambda or my `zipObj` in the last step, but very similar, down to the name chosen!

Answer (score 2):

I like to think of these problems as series of transformations, joined with `pipe` or `compose`.

```js
const count = pipe (
  countBy (identity),
  toPairs,
  map (zipObj (['name', 'y']))
)

console .log (count (['pending', 'pending', 'hired']))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, countBy, identity, toPairs, map, zipObj} = R       </script>
```

Here we first use `countBy` to convert to `{pending: 2, hired: 1}`.  Then with `toPairs`, we make `[['pending', 2], ['hired', 1]]`.  Finally, we `map` `zipObj` to convert those arrays into appropriate objects, `[{"name": "pending", "y": 2}, {"name": "hired", "y": 1}]`

Answer (score 1):

The answers from [Hitmands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68130748) and [Scott Sauyet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68130881) are excellent and I thoroughly endorse them.

I would like to show an alternative path of implementing this. First of all with plain JavaScript, we can do a count into a Map, then take that map as an iterable into [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to transform into objects:

```js
const countBy = (mapping, input) => {
  const m = new Map();
  for (const item of input) {
    const key = mapping(item);
    m.set(key, (m.get(key) ?? 0) + 1);
  }
  return m.entries();
};

const identity = x => x;

const count = input =>
  Array.from(
    countBy(identity, input), 
    ([name, y]) => ({name, y})
  );

console.log(count(['pending', 'pending', 'hired']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

This can be transformed into Ramda parlance with:

```js
//custom implementation
// (a → b) → [a] → [[b, Number]]
const countBy = curry((mapping, input) => {
  const m = new Map();
  for (const item of input) {
    const key = mapping(item);
    m.set(key, (m.get(key) ?? 0) + 1);
  }
  return m.entries();
});

const arrayFrom = pipe(binary, flip, curry) (Array.from);

const count = pipe (
  countBy(identity),
  arrayFrom(zipObj(["name", "y"]))
);

console.log(count(['pending', 'pending', 'hired']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, curry, identity, flip, zipObj, binary} = R; </script>
```

With this, you'd be able to group not only strings but any data types, as a map will preserve whatever data was put in:

```js
//custom implementation
// (a → b) → [a] → [[b, Number]]
const countBy = curry((mapping, input) => {
  const m = new Map();
  for (const item of input) {
    const key = mapping(item);
    m.set(key, (m.get(key) ?? 0) + 1);
  }
  return m.entries();
});

const arrayFrom = pipe(binary, flip, curry) (Array.from);

const count = pipe (
  countBy(identity),
  arrayFrom(zipObj(["name", "y"]))
);

console.log(" --- numbers --- ");
console.log(count([1, 2, "1", 2]));


console.log(" --- objects --- ");
const o1 = {foo: 1};
const o2 = {foo: 2};
const o3 = {foo: 1};
console.log(count([o1, o2, o3, o2]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, curry, identity, flip, zipObj, binary} = R; </script>
```

Again, this implementation is likely unneeded. But it might be of interest in some rare cases.

Comment: Note: my skill with Hindley-Milner notation is weak. I'm aware `[[b, Number]]` is not the correct type but I'm not sure how to express "iterable of `[b, Number]` tuples". I'm open to corrections and suggestions.

Comment: The Ramda team is always trying to extend H-M to handle JS constructs, and I've never been quite satisfied with the results.  That looks as good as anything I can think of.

Comment: I like the `Map`-based `countBy`.  But I'm curious as to the rationale for `arrayFrom`.  ISTM that it would simply be easier to pipe `Array.from` to `map (zipObj (["name", "y"]))`.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @ScottSauyet I guess just me trying to make a shortcut and not make an intermediary array but directly consume the iterator and map it in the process. You're quite right that `pipe ( countBy(identity), Array.from, map(zipObj(["name", "y"])) );` has the same result. There is no deeper meaning than my preference. I also recognise that the transformation to get `arrayFrom` is a bit ugly. TBH, I'd normally just use [a generator to map over an iterable](https://jsbin.com/lohisin/1/edit?html,js,console). But it's superfluous here, since `Array.from(map(f, xs))` is  the same as `Array.from(xs, f)`.